# Facebook Comment

Tags: facebook, comments

Hello I am the Site Administrator on www.mondoitech.com, I integrated Facebook comments in the articles, but when I have to moderate the comments I get this error:

> Cannot edit global settings or moderation mode without fb:app_id

How do I fix this error? I have followed various guides but did not succeed.

Comment: Throw the code you used to implement it on here.  Either one of your tags is marked up incorrectly or missing all together.

Comment: I used a plugin. Can you help me? is an Italian girl, a little clumsy to do these things. Thank you! :)

Comment: Facebook comments Plug in for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you will need to add the domain of your blog to the Facebook Application settings

Please refer this link http://wp-connect.tomasvorobjov.com/faq/#comments-moderation-access and complete all steps

Comment: I did it this way but still does not work. Can you help me? http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/310/66498704.jpg